Why is my async code no faster than synchronous?
So I had built a data pipeline which fetches reports from api endpoints, does some basic cleaning transformations and then concatenates the data into a an output dataframe. Originally I used multiprocessing, but that is no longer an option in the platform we use. Eager to try async, I made a testing suite and compared the performance of n runs with 4 reports, using async, multithreading, and synchronous-looped calls.
However, I was surprised that my async code was no faster statistically (using anova 1-way) than the synchronous code. I can only assume that I am not writing async in the most optimal way. Could someone advise if something is wrong here:
class AsyncApiCaller(ApiCaller):
    # snip
    async def async_build_and_assert_dataframe_from_csv(self, data):
        df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(data))
        if len(df) > 0:
            print("Warning: Dataframe is empty")
        return df

    async def process(self, session, url):
        result = await self.api_get(session, url)
        return await self.async_build_and_assert_dataframe_from_csv(
            result.decode("utf-8")
        )

    async def make_all_requests(self, ids):
        async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
            tasks = set()
            for url in ids:
                task = asyncio.create_task(coro=self.process(session=session, url=url))
                tasks.add(task)
            return await asyncio.gather(*tasks, return_exceptions=False)

    async def api_get(self, session, url: str):
        async with session.get(url, headers=self.headers) as response:
            return await response.content.read()

    async def main(self) -> pd.DataFrame:
        # snip
        urls = # a list of urls to run
        results = await self.make_all_requests(urls)

        # concat results into single DataFrame
        final_df = pd.concat(results)
        final_df = self.format_df(final_df)
        # snip
        return final_df
    #snip

The parent class is the synchronous version which I will omit most of the details here...
class ApiCaller:
   # snip
    def go_single(self, id: ID) -> pd.DataFrame:
        url = self.get_url(id) # turn id into an endpoint url
        response = self.call_api(url, "GET", headers) # requests library wrapper 
        data = self.parse_json_response(response, "data")
        dataframe = self.build_and_assert_dataframe_from_json(data)

        return dataframe

    def main(self) -> pd.DataFrame:
        # snip
        ids = # list of ids
        tasks = [self.go_single(id) for id in ids]
        dataframe = pd.concat(list(tasks), axis=0, ignore_index=False)
        dataframe = self.format_df(dataframe)
        # snip
        return dataframe
        

Multithreading code omitted.

async_build_and_assert_dataframe_from_csv is not async in any way. Drop the asyncs and awaits from it, they do nothing but add overhead to wrap synchronous code in futures. Note that if the work done to process the data is long enough, async won't help at all (it's for avoiding blocking on I/O, it won't speed up CPU-bound work).

The only thing that can benefit from async is the HTTP part; converting a CSV to a dataframe is CPU-bound.

Thanks, I've dropped the async and await on the processing, and will test performance speeds now. Does that mean we would expect in situations like this multithreading to be the fastest option?

Multithreading is limited by the GIL so it does not help to speed up CPU bound codes in most case (unless the GIL is disable which is often not possible).
